# Display a value each time it changes in a repeater

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an angularjs repeater.

```
 <tbody data-ng-repeat="game in model.Games | unique:'Number'">
    <tr><td colspan="3">{{game.Location}}</td></tr>
    <tr>
       <td>{{game.Number}}</td>
       <td>{{game.Away}}</td>
       <td>{{game.Home}}</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

In `game` there is a property `Location` that will remain constant then change at some point, for instance:

```
[
    { Number: 1, Location: 'Place 1', Home: 'Team 1', Away: 'Team 2' },
    { Number: 1, Location: 'Place 1', Home: 'Team 3', Away: 'Team 4' },
    { Number: 2, Location: 'Place 1', Home: 'Team 1', Away: 'Team 2' },
    { Number: 2, Location: 'Place 1', Home: 'Team 3', Away: 'Team 4' },
    { Number: 3, Location: 'Place 2', Home: 'Team 1', Away: 'Team 2' },
    { Number: 3, Location: 'Place 2', Home: 'Team 3', Away: 'Team 4' },
    { Number: 4, Location: 'Place 2', Home: 'Team 1', Away: 'Team 2' },
    { Number: 4, Location: 'Place 2', Home: 'Team 3', Away: 'Team 4' }
]
```

Each time it changes I want to display it's value, but not display it when it's repeating.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking for, you can just use `ng-show` to only show the row where the current Location is not equal to the previous Location.

```
<tr ng-show="game.Location != model.Games[$index-1].Location">
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xBwQqpt71FAiMlZHtoG2?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

[Working Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wUS4JkVBIiapL2MUDn20?p=preview)

You can create a filter for the grouping.  Every iteration will check if Location is encountered for the first time, and if it is, it will add a `IsFirst:true` property to the game object.

```
 app.filter('groupByLocation', function() {

     return function (input) {
       var groupedGames = [];  
       var location = null;
       var isFirst = false;
       angular.forEach(input, function(game) {
          if (location == null) {
              isFirst = true;
              location = game.Location;
          }
          else {
            if (location != game.Location) {
              isFirst = true;
              location = game.Location;
            }else {
              isFirst = false;
            }
          }
          if (isFirst)
              angular.extend(game, { IsFirst: true });
          groupedGames.push(game);


      });
       return groupedGames;           
   };
 });
```

You can then use ng-show and your filter to only show the row when `group.IsFirst` is `true`:

```
     <table data-ng-repeat="group in games | groupByLocation">
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-show="group.IsFirst"><td colspan="3">{{group.Location}}</td></tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>{{group.Number}}</td>
                  <td>{{group.Away}}</td>
                  <td>{{group.Home}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```